# Kendo UI MVVM unclear behavior

Tags: javascript, mvvm, kendo-ui, telerik, observable

Having the following JavaScript code, I am wondering why the person.Name property is not being updated when the modify() function is called on button click.

```
var person = { 
  Id: 1, 
  Name: "John" 
};

var model = kendo.observable({
  start: function() {
    kendo.bind($("#test"), this);
  },
  modify: function(){
    var self = this;
    self.Name = "John Doe";
    console.log(self.Name);
    console.log(person.Name);
  }
});

var person = $.extend({}, person, model);
person.start();
```

JSFiddle [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/bqhpfj2j/)

Answer (score 2):

It's because you are only updating the self variable in the "modify" function scope. You are not updating the "person" variable. Your call to jQuery's extend function is not binding/associating the person object to the model.

An example of using the [kendo.observable](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/observableobject#getting-started) object class to achieve what you want is shown below:

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
  person: {
    id: 1,
    name: "John"
  },
  modify: function(e) {
    console.log(viewModel.person.get("name"));
    viewModel.person.set("name", "John Doe");
    console.log(viewModel.person.get("name"));
  }
});

kendo.bind($("#test"), viewModel);
```

and a working jsfiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/rqtyer5y/).

The key points to note are that the person object is defined as part of the observable object, it's not merged afterwards. Also it's crucial that you read or update the observable values using its "get" and "set" [methods](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/observableobject#field-values).

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.
The code I shared is a simplified version of a much larger code I was reviewing. I understand the example you shared, but I am not sure it answers my question.
In my code, when person.start() is called, my understanding is that "this" should refer to the person object. You can verify that by updating person.Id before calling kendo.bind in the start method.

Comment: No problem @Joe. The first two sentence state the problem, but I'll  add more detail here. The call to $.extend uses a new object as the first parameter. Hence when you are interacting with it's person object, you are not interacting with the person object defined at the start of your code. I've forked your code snippet and added some comments for clarity https://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/corovmn1/

Comment: Hey @BenSmith, thank you again. You're saying the call to $.extend uses a new object as the first param, that's true, but I am reassigning this object to person, so it's basically the same as calling $.extend(person, model).
I think I found what the problem is: before calling person.start(), person should be an observable object. The thing is that when $.extend combines an observable object (model) with a non-observable object (person), the result is a non-observable object. Here are 2 ways to making it work: https://jsfiddle.net/bqhpfj2j/5/ and https://jsfiddle.net/bqhpfj2j/6/

Comment: Yes, your reassignment was wrong. I said in my answer "Your call to jQuery's extend function is not binding/associating the person object to the model.". When I say not binding to the person object, it means its not binding to your person object which is part of your kendo observable object...